Improve traction on icy path to campsite
I have a campsite on crown (public) land in Eastern Ontario that I use for winter camping. There is a 100ft path on a slope from the logging road down to the campsite. The snow on top of the pine needles has packed down due to foot traffic and has become icy. I’ve almost slipped several times and am worried I’ll fall and hit my head on a rock.
How can I improve traction on the icy trail? I’d prefer not to use salt or a sand/salt mix because I think the salt would harm the trees; neither I nor the government would like that.
I tried smashing the ice with a sledge hammer and iron pry bar, but the ice was too solid and there was too much of it to make a dent in it.

Wear crampons??

Yak Tracks are an option too

If you're really worried, you could wear a ski helmet to protect your head.  When I first wore one snowboarding I noticed it also kept my head much warmer.  OK, goofy, but you're in the middle of nowhere.

my first thought was "if salt or sand/salt would be an option if not for the harm to the trees, why not just use sand or gravel without salt to improve traction?" - but it's possible that the ice is too hardened for this to be effective (on really smooth, hard ice the sand/gravel may have trouble biting into it and not make enough of a difference). Leaving this as comment here anyway, in case the ice is not THAT hard. If it is though, the sand/gravel might give people a false sense of security and do more harm than good.

Why not sprinkle salt?

Answer to comment "Why not sprinkle salt?"  First, this is public land, not private property, and should be treated with the same consideration as a neighbor's private property.  You would not sprinkle salt on your neighbor's land without permission.  Second, salt is not good for vegetation, and you have no control over how much salt will be sprinkled by others, once you start the habit.

Depending on the exact situation, something between ice cleats, microspikes, and full-on crampons will work. The tiny points will easily bite into the ice and give you traction.
I always keep a pair of ice cleats and a pair of microspikes when hiking in winter conditions, and I've used both on trails with significant slopes, including in conditions where the ice was very hard.
Ice cleats are a great improvement in traction, especially on very smooth ice. They are not so useful when there is a bit of snow on top, as they get jammed.
Microspikes are perfect for anything between black ice and packed snow, just a bit heavier and more cumbersome that cleats.
Crampons are probably overkill for most situations not involving a mountain.
(Note: The original yaktrax and equivalent (the ones which are just a sort of spring passing under your shoes) are useless for ice. You need something with actual pointy bits)

Pro tip: If it's for home use just have a pair of old shoes with microspikes permanently installed and wear them whenever it's icy.

One of the suggestions in the Comments, to wear Yak Tracks, doesn't seem likely to work well under the conditions you describe, which is:

I tried smashing the ice with a sledge hammer and iron pry bar, but
the ice was too solid and there was too much of it to make a dent in
it.

However, as @njzk2 said in a comment below, crampons are designed to work on hard ice.
You don't say how steep the slope is, or what is at the bottom of the slope (soft snow?  large tree?  drop-off?) but assuming the slope is not steep and the end of the slope is soft, going down on your rear end might work.
You might also walk parallel to the beaten down track, where the surface is softer, and you might have trees to glom onto.
The suggestion to wear a helmet would address your principal concern to spare your head, but going down backwards on all fours  -- again, depending on the steepness of the slope might also work.
Without more information on the nature of the slope, I would try a combination of walking slightly off-trail where the track is not beaten down plus either going down on all fours or on your rear end.
I was on an icy patch on a trail outside of Telluride, where everyone was having difficulty, except for a dog. Click! Four paws!  So I got down on all fours and had no problem.

Crampons are literally meant to be used on hard ice. A sharp crampon spike will hold on ice regardless of whether you're able to beat it with a hammer or not

The are no pictures and no details, so here are my few cents.

Claws ice grips - because the Yak Tracks seem to be suitable only for gentleman-y ice.
Install a chain along the path - to function as a rail. If there are some trees (as you mention), it is better, because suspending the chain will prevent it becoming embedded in the snow / ice. You may suspend the chain to poles fixed in the ground - if the ground would be nice to accept them at those temperatures. Homework for next summer.
Wear some cloth on the bottom of your boots - it has a chance to improve traction (although it might not; usually recommended for horizontal slippery paths).
If snowing stopped, just apply simple sand. It will embed itself in the ice, and offer you traction.
Install plain old stairs - each step sloped to help you stay on the stairs, instead of helping you fall to the bottom of the hill. They should have some rails, just for a good measure.
You can hack some stairs by digging them into the ground. Easier to do during the summer, easier to clean with some of the tools below.
Other hacked stairs: just buy the cheapest stairs you find, bolt them down to the path somehow. They will still provide more help than you already have.

Some options work better if you are alone (or only a few people), other options are more suited for heavier traffic.

Joke (or not): a flame thrower? Just stay away from the cameras, when they come to record the burning forest, for the news channel. Actually, the flame thrower is a bad idea and dangerous - please do NOT use it.
Another joke (or not): a good hammer drill. If it breaks cement, it will break the ice too. It also requires less elbow grease, compared to a manual hammer. An 100ft is not the end of the world for an electrical extender cord.
Yet another joke (or not): a good leaf blower. It will easily remove fresh snow, before it has a chance to compress and become ice.


Now that the damage is already done, hacks are relatively difficult. But with some planning, you could do some better hacks during the summer to get prepared for the next winter.

+1 The temporary rail has real merit.   As for the flame thrower, I suggest you delete it or make it clear that it is a bad idea -- not just a joke.

Put on a helmet to protect your noggin.  Then tie a rope to something fixed at the top of the path.  Next, use that rope to help you navigate the path.  Having an stable point of contact, at a different angle, will serve as significant assistance in traversing the path in both directions.
On the way down the path, you can even use the ice to your advantage by sitting down and placing your rear on anything slippery such as a small sled, inflated innertube, piece of a cardboard box, doormat, or folded tarp.  You can then ease yourself down the path using the rope.  You'll start to enjoy your little journey to your campsite instead of dreading it!

The main concern when walking on ice is not a (severe) head injury but arm or leg injuries. Torn ligaments and broken bones are not uncommon. A helmet will help very little. Microspikes are the way to go.

@Michael The OP stated they are concerned about sustaining a head injury.  If you have a different answer, please do post it so we can all benefit.
